# Генератор случайных чисел: float в диапазоне 0 до 1

Tags: c#, .net, случайные-числа

Для некоторой задачи мне нужен генератор случайных чисел с плавающей запятой (float) от 0.0f до 1.0f, при одном seed генерирующий все те же значения каждый запуск.

Comment: И что, в стандартной библиотеке C# такого генератора нет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin путь даже есть - это не повод закрывать вопрос

Comment: Все очень за вас рады. И в чем же проблема? Или вы хотите ,чтобы кто-нибудь сделала вместо вас вашу работу?

Comment: @PashaPash: мне в самом деле было непонятно, в чем проблема. А ещё автор явно делал попытки, но кода нет; неясно, какие решения уже были опробованы.

Comment: @metalurgus на вопрос есть принятый ответ. очевидно, автору ответа было вполне понятна суть вопроса, раз он смог подробно, с кодом, ответить. мне тоже вполне понятна, кстати.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так сойдёт?

```
int seed = 1000;
Random rnd = new Random(seed);
float value = (float)rnd.NextDouble();
```

Ну а если вам нужен произвольный диапазон, то это легко добавить:

```
public static class RandomExts
{
    public static double NextDouble (this Random @this, double min, double max)
    {
        return @this.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
    }

    public static double NextFloat (this Random @this, float min, float max)
    {
        return (float)@this.NextDouble(min, max);
    }
}
```

Соответственно, использование:

```
float value = rnd.NextFloat(0, 1);
```

Comment: Забавно! Я делал 'Random Rnd = new Random(seed);' глобально прямо в классе и получал случайные значения. Через пару минут смогу выбрать ваш ответ как лучший.